# Constructing non-aggregate object using brackets

Tags: c++

I'm rather a beginner in C++ and yesterday I came across a constructor I don't understand.

```
struct Person
{
    explicit Person(std::vector<std::function<void (float)>> &update_loop)
    {
        update_loop.emplace_back([this](float dt) { update(dt); });
    }

    void update(float dt);
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<void (float)>> update_loop;

    Person person { update_loop };
}
```

I know it's possible to initialize aggregate objects in this way, but `Person` doesn't have data members, just a constructor and a function, so what exactly `Person person { update_loop }` does? If it uses the explicit constructor shouldn't it use round parentheses, like `Person person(update_loop)` ?

Comment: BTW if there is a user-provided constructor then a class is no longer an aggregate; data members or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax here

```
Person person { update_loop };
```

Is the new "uniform initialization" syntax (introduced in C++11) and is part of the general [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

In your case, using the `()` or the `{}` would be equivalent, but this is not always the case. `{}` does not allow narrowing conversions etc. and it also avoids the "most vexing parse" issues found with `()`.